# Access a Flask extension that is defined in the app factory

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I am using the app factory pattern to set up my Flask application.  My app uses the Flask-Babel extension, and that is set up in the factory as well.  However, I want to access the extension in a blueprint in order to use it,

The factory is in `__init__.py`.

```
def create_app(object_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(object_name)

    babel = Babel(app)

    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(category_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(item_blueprint)

    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

I want to add the following to `main.py`:

```
@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    if 'locale' in session:
        return session['locale']
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(LANGUAGES.keys())

@application.route('/locale/<locale>/', methods=['GET'])
def set_locale(locale):
    session['locale'] = locale
    redirect_to = request.args.get('redirect_to', '/')
    return redirect(redirect_to)     # Change this to previous url
```

Unfortunately, `main.py` doesn't have access to the `babel` variable from the application factory.  How should I go about solving this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flask extensions are designed to be instantiated without an app instance for exactly this case.  Outside the factory, define your extensions.  Inside the factory, call `init_app` to associate the app with the extension.

```
babel = Babel()

def create_app():
    ...
    babel.init_app(app)
    ...
```

Now the `babel` name is importable at any time, not just after the app has been created.

---

<sub>You already appear to be doing this correctly with the `db` (Flask-SQLAlchemy) extension.</sub>

---

<sub>In the case of your specific `babel.localeselector` example, it might make more sense to put that next to `babel` since it's being defined there.</sub>